# Why does unsafe code compile, but similar code that pushes to a vector complains that a reference doesn't live long enough?

Tags: rust, unsafe, lifetime

I have something like the following Rust code, which can store a Rust object somewhere (in the real application it's stored in a Lua userdata) and retrieve it later (when calling methods from Lua).

```
use std::ptr;

struct Bar(u32);

struct Foo<'a> {
    subobj: &'a Bar,
}

struct State {
    buf: [u8;100],
}

fn stash<T>(state: &mut State, foo: T) {
    let p : *mut T = state.buf.as_ptr() as *mut T;
    unsafe { ptr::write(p, foo); };
}

fn fetch<T>(state: &mut State) -> &mut T {
    let p : *mut T = state.buf.as_ptr() as *mut T;
    unsafe { &mut *p }
}

fn main() {
    let mut state = State{buf: [0;100]};
    // let mut v: Vec<Foo> = Vec::new();
    {
        let bar = Bar(7);
        let foo = Foo { subobj: &bar };

        // v.push(foo); // *does* complain that bar doesn't live long enough
        stash(&mut state, foo);
    }  // bar's lifetime ends here!
    let foo2: &mut Foo = fetch(&mut state); // Boom!

    println!("{}", foo2.subobj.0 + 3);
}
```

The example above is clearly wrong, since it allows me to get a dangling reference to `bar` after its scope has ended.  However it would seem fine with any type not containing any references (or only `'static` ones), or something like `Rc<T>`.

Why does that compile, but a very similar program (push to a vector instead) complains (as desired) that the reference to `bar` doesn't live long enough?  I don't really understand what's different with `Vec::push`.

My understanding is that typechecking only looks at function signatures and not function bodies. For these purposes, the `unsafe` code shouldn't be relevant; the point is that I'm trying to figure out how to wrap the `unsafe` code into a safe interface.

Comment: This compiles because in unsafe code, it's up to the programmer to make sure that dereferencing a pointer is actually safe.

Comment: 100% agree with A.B. here. An `unsafe` block tells the compiler "I will uphold all the memory-safety guarantees myself because the compiler cannot verify them for me" and then you go and violate all the memory-safety guarantees.

Comment: But the `unsafe` code is hidden inside functions - I was under the impression that type checking stopped at the prototype, rather than peeking inside - and `Vec` surely has unsafe code under the hood too.

Comment: You must call `std::mem::forget(foo)` in `stash`, otherwise `foo`'s destructor will run at the end of `stash`.

Comment: I don't think `mem::forget` is needed. `foo` is moved into `ptr::write`.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson: You're right, for some reason I thought it took the value by reference, but it should be obvious from usage (if not from looking at the documentation) that it doesn't. :|

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But the `unsafe` code is hidden inside functions - I was under the impression that type checking stopped at the prototype, rather than peeking inside - and `Vec` surely has unsafe code under the hood too.

You are correct that type checking stops at the prototype. The difference here is that a `Vec` includes the type you are storing in it's own type - it's a `Vec<T>`!

Before I get too far into an answer, I'd encourage you to read [*The Rustonomicon*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/), which talks about how `Vec` is implemented and how `unsafe` can be used judiciously.

To make your code fail in the same way as a vector, you can encode the stored type with [`PhantomData`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html):

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct State<T> {
    buf: [u8; 100],
    marker: PhantomData<T>
}

fn stash<T>(state: &mut State<T>, foo: T) { ... }
fn fetch<T>(state: &mut State<T>) -> &mut T { ... }
```

Now, when you `stash` the reference in the inner block, the type of the `State` is inferred to hold a reference and that reference has a lifetime. Then the normal lifetime mechanics prevent using it outside of the block.

If you want to see the code in a working state, note that you'd have to move `let bar = Bar(7);` before the creation of `State` as well:

```
fn main() {
    let bar = Bar(7);

    let mut state = State {
        buf: [0;100],
        marker: PhantomData,
    };

    let foo = Foo { subobj: &bar };
    stash(&mut state, foo);

    let foo2: &mut Foo = fetch(&mut state);

    println!("{}", foo2.subobj.0 + 3);
}
```

---

I won't say that the code I've written here is actually safe - that takes more thinking and verification!

Comment: I literally read this part of the Rustonomicon this morning on the train to work and I was struggling to picture where that might be useful outside of the example in Vec. Thanks for this!

Comment: Thanks, I'll go back and read The Rustonomicon again now it's more immediately relevant!